# Batch file that adds number to filename each time it runs

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to figure out how tag on an 8 digit sequence at the end of a filename. The goal is to get the filename looking something like this "TEST_FILENAME_TV_00000001.dat". Each time this process runs, the number should increment by one. Once the file is run by this process, it's automatically uploaded to a server, so I'm not storing them locally.

I'm no programmer, but here is what I have in my batch file regards to this process:

```
(some mapping)  

set num=0
set /a num=num+1

REN *.dat *.
REN *. *%num%.
REN *. *.dat

(upload file process)
```

This leaves me with the output "TEST_FILENAME_TV_1.dat" only adds the number 1 to the file, each time it runs. Is it possible to increment this without checking other files? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It would greatly help us to provide an in context solution if you were to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61737389/edit), to include at least the `(some mapping)` code. In addition to that you need to open a Command Prompt window, and read the usage information for the commands you'll probably need for this task. `for /?`, `dir /?` or `where /?`, `findstr /?`, `set /?`, `setlocal /?`, `set /?` and `ren /?`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this FOR loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55418067/can-someone-please-tell-me-whats-wrong-with-this-for-loop) You can find more similar answers with a seach for `[batch-file] increment number in filename`